# What is the JSON global object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading that the best way to parse JSON in the browser is by using the `JSON.parse()` method.

Sorry, I've been living under a rock — where the hell did this `JSON` global object come from? Is it defined in some standard? Is it available in all browsers? When should I use [Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) instead?

Comment: It is not available in all browsers. You can test for the availability of that top-level object and load a parser if you like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is part of ECMAScript 5, and is the Object with the internal class JSON that holds relevant methods (`stringify` and `parse`) for processing JSON data.

Use the json2 library in browsers where JSON is not implemented.

You could test for it like this:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( window.JSON ) !== '[object JSON]' ) {
    // load the library
}
```

Comment: @patrick dw: why not check this way: `if ( !("JSON" in window) ) { _load library }` - looks shorter ;)

Comment: @Maxym: Yes, there are a few ways you could test it. This way ensures that it is the actual JSON object implemented according to the spec. A simpler test using the `in` operator would work, but would also return a positive result for any truthy value that someone may have assigned to `window.JSON`. Simply a matter of preference I guess. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw: the same way somebody can create JSON object with `toString: function() {return "[object JSON]";}` ;)

Comment: Or you could simply do like Crockford does in his library: `if(!JSON)` it really doesn't have to be much harder than that, and 99% of the time anything else is overkill.

Comment: @Maxym: Actually no. This method calls the `.toString()` of `Object.prototype`, placing the object you're testing as the *thisArg* argument for `.call()`. As such, you're not calling the `toString()` of the object itself, but rather you're using the `toString()` of `Object.prototype` to get the internal [[Class]] property. This is a property that can't be altered outside the implementation.

Comment: @Maxym: You can read a little more about it in the spec here: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6.2

Comment: Above I stated *"the `in` operator would work, but would also return a positive result for any truthy value"*, when in fact the `in` operator would return a positive result as long as the property had been initialized with *any* value, even `undefined`. Example: `window.blah = undefined; alert( 'blah' in window ); // true` This is because `in` tests for mere existence of a property irrespective of its value.